# Laravel sail installation problem (The specified path could not be found)

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I'm trying to install Sail for Laravel by doing :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject
cd myproject
composer require laravel/sail --dev

php artisan sail:install
```

But I'm getting as Output :

> Sail scaffolding installed successfully.
> The specified path could not be found

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Docker? Is this inside a Dockerfile? What version of PHP and Docker are you using?

Comment: Does myproject/vendor/bin/sail exist? Does `docker info` run successfully? The "Sail scaffolding installed successfully." output happens right before the Sail installer tries to run `./vendor/bin/sail build`. Also, what operating system?

Comment: If you install a new `laravel/laravel` project, it will already come with `sail`, so I would do that...

Comment: If you are using windows, to run your commands, first open **cmd** in admin mode (in start menu type cmd, right click on the app and select run as administrator). then follow your steps, and at last do ```./vendor/bin/sail up``` in your project.